# Android EditText: Disable edit but allow copy

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created an `EditTextView` in Android Studio. I would like to disable the possibilty to edit the pre-existing text while enabling the user to select and copy the text inside.

Before, it was possible to do it with:

```
android:editable="false"
```

Now however, this is deprecated and it doesn't work anymore.
I tried to use:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

or

```
android:focusable="false"
```

This surely makes the text non-editable but there is no way for the user to select and copy it then.

Is there another way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: I would like to be able to select parts of the text and copy those that I want, just like the old behaviour of `android:editable="false"`